# Why doesn't this bot successfully mute the specified user?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to create a discord bot which is able to mute a certain user when the bot is invoked like ',mute @'. The command should add the muted role to the user, so that they are not able to send messages.

I have the following code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=',')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord and is ready to mute!')

@client.command(aliases=[',mute'])
async def mute(member: discord.Member):
    role = get(member.server.roles, name='Muted')
    await member.add_roles(member, role)

if member.has_role('Muted'):
    await member.channel.send(f'{member} has been muted')
```

When I try using the command, I see no apparent effect. Why doesn't the role get added?

Comment: So you want to give someone a role so that they cannot write something?

Comment: Yes, basically a mute

Comment: And you‘ve already created that role?

Comment: yes, I have already created it

Comment: So your problem is that the bot doesn‘t add the role although you and the bot have the permission to do that? (btw: not sure, but it seems weird using member twice in `member.add_role(member, role)`

Answer (score 2):

1. You don't have to add your prefix to aliases, it's being automatically added.
2. It's [`member.Guild.roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.roles), not `.server` (Don't worry, this doesn't only happen to you)
3. The right usage of  [`member.add_roles()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.add_roles) is `member.add_roles(THE_ROLE_YOU_WANT_TO_ADD)`, as described in the docs. So, easy explanation: If you have `member.add_roles()` you don't have to give the `member` parameter to the function.
4. I guess you want the `if` in the function so I moved it there with a `return` and another message so if he already got the role it doesn't try to add it and saves a lot of time. Also; you can't get a channel from the member as the member doesn't belong to a channel.
5. For commands, you always have to pass the `context` (aka 'ctx') parameter first. So you can take that to send back your bot's response.

So your revised code is:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=',')


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord and is ready to mute!')


@client.command(aliases=['mute'])
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    if member.has_role('Muted'):
        return await ctx.send(f'{member} is already muted!')

    role = get(member.Guild.roles, name='Muted')
    await member.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(f'{member} has been muted!')
```